# How to reshape an 1-D numpy array into 2-D numpy array with values by rows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have an array:

```
x = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])
```

I'd like to convert it to 2-D array, but with subsequent values input by rows:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

I thought that since `x.reshape(-1, 3)` fills the values by columns, then `x.reshape(3, -1)` would give me my expected output, but that's not the case. I could obviously do `x.reshape(3, -1).T` but I'd love to understand why `reshape` gives me the same results no matter of the arguments order and what's the **proper** way to do that with one method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the order parameter in reshape to `'F'` ('Fortran'):

```
>>> x = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])
>>> x.reshape(3,-1, order='F')
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Check out: [`numpy.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

Answer (score 1):

When you pass -1 to reshape it just means that you don't specify how many rows or columns you want. So when you do `x.reshape(-1, 3)` it just means you want 3 columns and you let numpy *decide* how many rows to use. And when you do `x.reshape(3, -1)` it just means you want 3 rows and let numpy decide how many columns to use. So it doesn't change the result.

What you basically have to do is `x.reshape(3, -1).transpose()` or `x.reshape(-1, 3).transpose()`

You can't just do it with one method.